# what am I doing wrong in my setTimeout call?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I am trying to write some code that displays text, and then removes it two seconds later, however, the setTimeout() method doesn't seem to be working properly for me, the function that is called is running with no delay. Here's the code:

```
IDtext('IP-saved', "New IP Address saved successfully!");
setTimeout(IDtext('IP-saved', ""), 2000);

function IDtext(ID, text) {
    document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML = text;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to pass a reference to a function to `setTimeout()`. Your code passes the result of **calling** the function.

Comment: `setTimeout(IDtext('IP-saved', "")` invokes `IDtext('IP-saved', "")` immediately, you need a function that, when called, invokes IDtext instead

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is

```
setTimeout(IDtext, 2000, 'IP-saved', '');
```

the arguments of the referenced function must be placed last

see documentaion of [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

your syntax way is
`var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(function[, delay, arg1, arg2, ...]);`

Comment: Wow, I never knew arguments could be passed this way! I usually do `setTimeout( IDtext.bind(this,'IP-saved', ''), 2000);`

Comment: @JeremyThille  the first argument is a **reference** to your function, not a call to your function.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm not calling the function, I'm binding it to the current context and passing it the arguments.

Comment: @JeremyThille  you can also use an arrow function to economize bind usage

Comment: I know but I prefer the bind syntax

Comment: Thanks so much! the tutorial I was looking at mentioned nothing about parameters, so that's where I got tripped up.